# Review Audit quality?

Tags: bug, review-audits

Related question - [Where to ask for advice regarding a review audit?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/where-to-ask-for-advice-regarding-a-review-audit)

I just ran into a review Audit:

[image]

The question for which the first post occured was: [Are certifications worth it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-certifications-worth-it)

I checked the question, but could not find the answer on the page. In the review box, it wasn't possible to either down/up vote, nor flag or comment the post, since the quesiton is marked as wiki.  The only actions available were: share(on the answer), Nothing needs to be done(review), Skip(review). Since the answer wasn't visible on the question page and I couldn't find the user, I clicked "Nothing needs to be done", assuming that it had already been deleted.

In retrospect, "Skip" probably would have been the better choice, but is this really a good review audit scenario? First-posts on wiki questions aren't even possible, are they?

Comment: The audit appeared on the "first posts" queue. The (up/down)vote on the answer should have been available, as should have been the  "edit" and "delete" (for higher rep users) links under it. This smells like a bug.

Comment: I think they all weren't available, because the question was flagged as wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, the answer shouldn't have appeared in the review queue (neither as an audit, nor as a regular review). The reason is that [the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-certifications-worth-it) is [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), therefore it and its answers cannot be voted on or edited.

This is an [old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141435/new-beta-review-displays-locked-posts) that resurfaced, I will let SE know about it.